# По приходу или по приходе

Tags: орфография

По приходу правильно разве? Я до того как увидел это предложение думал, что правильно по приходе.
Представьте, господа, у нас хлеба ничуть нету!... Муж еще не ездил по приходу...

Answer (score 3):

Приход - община верующих, принадлежащая к одной церкви. Муж ещё не ездил по округе, где живут члены общины.

Приход -2 скл. муж. род.Дат.пад.(по чему?) по приходу, по лесу, по полю, по  округу. Почему по приходе? Вероятно, Вы перепутали с производным предлогом типа по приезде, по прибытии, по окончании.Предлоги в значении "после чего-то" - сочетание ПО+сущ. в предложном падеже, т.е. окончание -Е.

А по приходу-существительное в дат. пад., всё верно.

Comment: А я понял как, что муж после своего приезда или прихода откуда-то не ездил еще собирать хлеб. Теперь понятно. Спасибо. Ну да, он же поп по рассказу. Получается поп должен был ездить собирать хлеб со всех людей?

Comment: Ну, собирает-то он не хлеб, а подати деньгами, а хлеба потому и нет, что не на что якобы купить, ещё подати не собрал. Это совсем в давние времена да в голод  священники  подати хлебом брали

Answer (score 1):

А я понял как, что муж после своего приезда или прихода откуда-то не ездил еще собирать хлеб. Теперь понятно. Спасибо. Ну да, он же поп по рассказу. Получается поп должен был ездить собирать хлеб со всех людей?

Answer (score 1):

Людмила совершенно верно сказала. Вы смешали два разных значения слова "приход" - церковная административно-территориальная единица и действие по глаголу "приходить".

Я только добавлю, что в первом значении конструкция означает "после того, как", "при каком условии" и поэтому требует предложного падежа (по чём?) и в современном языке малоупотребительна вне устойчивых сочетаний (по прибытии, по предъявлении), а уж со словом "приход" - просто редкость.

А во втором - обычного дательного (ездил - "по чему?").